# How to bind a keycode to hyper key in Aquamacs

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, keystrokes, aquamacs, prefix-keys

I am using Aquamacs. I have used [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) to change my caps lock key to emit key code 110. I would like to bind that code to super/hyper/another modifier so that I can create more key combinations. How can I do that?